# Importing a collectiontype of localized Strings in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a collection like this:

```
<collectiontype code="colors" elementtype="localized:java.lang.String">
```

and an itemtype containing this collection:

```
<itemtype code="MyShirt" autocreate="true" generate="true">
 <attributes>
   <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
     <persistence type="property">
   </attribute>
   <attribute qualifier="colors" type="colors">
     <persistence type="property">
   </attribute>
 </attributes>
 </itemtype>
```

So what should be the proper ImpEx for inserting shirts in this itemtype:

```
   $lang=en
   INSERT_UPDATE MyShirt;code[unique=true];colors(code[lang=$lang])
```

The above statement gives error.Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here you try to add a localized collection, but I am not sure that Hybris allows you do that. So, I think you need to change the collection type to :

```
<collectiontype code="colors" elementtype="java.lang.String">
```

To import new elements, you have to change your Impex hedear and remove `(code[lang=$lang])`, colors is a list of `String` not `Objects` that have an attribute called `code`, So you have to use :

```
INSERT_UPDATE MyShirt;code[unique=true];colors
                     ;shirt_1;color1,color2,color
```

But, almost of the time, for this kind of requirements, Hybris call for using `Classifications`, `Attributes of classifications` and `Attributes value classifications`.

Answer (score 1):

CollectionTypes have been deprecated. Prefer relations. In your case I would introduce an itemtype "Color" and create a relation between "MyShirt" and "Color". For color you can create a unique id and reuse that color for all your shirts. I'm absolutely sure, different shirts may come in the same color. Additionally you can localize your colors at one point. You can be sure that changing a color name for a certain color has an effect on all your shirts. There are a multitude of advantages to this approach.